# makefile for java

Tags: java, makefile

i don't understand what i did wrong with my makefile :

```
JAVA_SRCS:=$(wildcard tasks/src/*.java)
JAVA_CLASSES=$(subst /src/,/build/,$(JAVA_SRCS:.java=.class))
JFLAGS=-cp jar/octobot.jar -d tasks/build
JC=javac

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
 $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

default: build

build: $(JAVA_CLASSES)

clean:
 $(RM) tasks/build/*.class
```

I got this error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `tasks/build/ClickTask.class', needed by `classes'.  Stop.
zsh: exit 2     make
```

But strangely, when i re-write the rule *build* like this :

```
build: $(JAVA_SRCS:.java=.class)
```

no error, the rule is launched but does it every time (and it's not correct)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Dean Povey is correct: you can't do this with suffix rules, because they look in the same directory as the source. You can, however, do this with a GNU Make pattern rule (and you're already using GNUMake-isms in your Makefile, so whatever):

```
tasks/build/%.class: tasks/src/%.java
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<
```

Note, however, that `make` is ill-suited to building java source as one `.java` file can result in many `.class` files (inner classes, for instance). Automake's approach to this problem is to compile everything in a single call to `javac` and write out a timestamp file (`echo timestamp > classnoinst.stamp`, for example). Then anything that needs the java sources built depends on that stamp file and `make clean` removes the `.stamp` along with the `.class` files.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because your src is in a different directory.  It is looking for tasks/build/ClickTask.java but your source is tasks/src/ClickTask.java.

The second case works because it finds the source file, but then expects the class file to end up in tasks/src, which it doesn't hence it rebuilds all the time.

I don't have a good answer for how to do this with Makefiles, I tend to just put class files in the same directory.  Alternatively, think about using Ant or Maven which supports this much more easily.

**EDIT:**  I think this should tell you what you need: http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-8-SECT-1.html