# Creating java compiler using makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I am very new to java and new to makefile.
I have a server which receives some programs, compile it and say if result is correct.
so i have to make a makefile which will be able to compile any incoming java program to server. I was told , that i have to use some tool to automatically create this file. Can someone explain what to do?

Comment: Makefile? What I(we) use to compile java is ant. Uses xml (make)files. The other way is to create a shell script and put what you need inside.

Comment: Try a quick google search: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783068/makefile-for-java and try to adapt all those examples. It shouldn't be too difficult to create them dynamically.